# selector for get all the first child with classname x

Tags: javascript, css, queryselector

I have this html structure

```html
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="rock"></li>
        <li class="paper"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="rock"></li>
        <li class="paper"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="paper"></li>
        <li class="rock"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="rock"></li>
        <li class="paper"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="paper"></li>
        <li class="rock"></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to get from the element with class container, all the first-child with class paper.

I tried

```js
let selected=document.querySelectorAll(".container:first-child.paper");
```

but was wrong.
How I get the correct query selector?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".container .paper:first-child");`

Comment: The first child selector targets an element that is the first child of a parent element - not the first child of a parent element - you probably want the following  - let selected=document.querySelectorAll(".container .paper:first-child");

Comment: Switch .paper with :first-child, and put space after .container.

Comment: CSS selectors are whitespace sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not correct to target the elements you are looking for.

Try

```
let selected = document.querySelectorAll(".container .paper:first-child");
```

**Demo:**

```js
let selected = document.querySelectorAll(".container .paper:first-child");
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="rock"></li>
  <li class="paper"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="rock"></li>
  <li class="paper"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="paper">1234</li>
  <li class="rock"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="rock"></li>
  <li class="paper"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="paper">ABCD</li>
  <li class="rock"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let selected= document.querySelectorAll(".container .paper:first-child");
selected.forEach(e => e.textContent = 'First Paper');
```

```html
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="rock"></li>
        <li class="paper"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="rock"></li>
        <li class="paper"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="paper"></li>
        <li class="rock"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="rock"></li>
        <li class="paper"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="container">
        <li class="paper"></li>
        <li class="rock"></li>
    </ul>
```